# PHP - How to use a div to wrap all items Inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, html

I have been scratching my head for half hour now trying to figure this out
I have a wrapper div inside a foreach loop and I'm trying to force it to echo one and not duplicate

```
    foreach ($apples as $apple) {
        //echo only once bellow
        <div class="Wrapper">
        //echo only once Above

        echo $apple;

        //echo only once bellow
        </div>
        //echo only once Above
    }
```

I do not wish to move my `Wrapper` div outside the foreach, It is very important for the div to be inside the foreach and to be without duplicates.

Comment: what is the reason to not put this `div` to outside of loop ?

Comment: That makes no sense. A wrapper is precisely the sort of thing you would do *outside* the loop, for the very fact it needs to be output once, not iteratively. If you really must do it inside, you need to set up a tracker variable which is set once it's output, then output the wrapper tags only if that variable has not yet been set.

Comment: use condition {for index} to print starting of div at element 1 and for last element close div?

Comment: Can you not post pseudo code please? What you have now isn't proper syntax. You're injecting pure HTML into PHP.

Comment: When you say you don't want to move the wrapper outside the loop, you're basically saying you don't want to do this the really obvious and straightforward way. Unless we know *why* you don't want to do that, we can't give you any decent answers.

Comment: Do have to agree that this is super low quality. Don't know why I answered the question to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention but If you need to put `Wrapper` div only if you have any count in `$apples` variable then simply check with `if(count($apples))` and then put `Wrapper`

```
<?php
    if(count($apples)){ 
      echo '<div class="Wrapper">';
      foreach ($apples as $apple) {
        echo $apple;
      }
      echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help since you want to keep it inside foreach loop

```
$numItems = count($arr);

$i = 0;

foreach($arr as $ar) {

    $i = $i+1;

    if ($i == 1) {
        echo '<div class="class">';
    }

    // do your stuff

    if($i == $numItems) {
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I know this is not good way to write but as per his condition I am suggesting this code.**

---

I don't know why you don't want to put `div` outside `foreach` loop but anyway you can use the following code to achieve that...

```
<?php
    foreach ($apples as $apple) {
        static $i = 0;
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo "<div class='Wrapper'>";
        }
        echo $apple;
        $i++;
        if ($i == count($apples)){
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This will only wrap the first item in the `<div>` all others will be on there own.